# Width of the column view separation line in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I'm using Mac OS X lion. In Finder, I use the column view. I know how to set up the width, but the thin line you use to drag the columns has suddenly become thicker and very visible.

I know this isn't a huge problem, but I don't know how it happened and don't know how to change it back.

I hope you know what I mean and how to get it back to default.

Comment: Is it just the track for the scroll bars, or did you change the setting for showing scroll bars in System Preferences? If not, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It's the thin line you drag to adjust the width.
I just checked in the system preferences and I fixed it! 
I pressed -> System prefrences -> appereance -> show scroll bars: when scrolling.

So suddenly, this changed the appearance of the column lines.

Thank you for your comment, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 14):

You must have a mouse plugged in.
In `System Preferences > General`, under the "Show Scroll bars" section, there are three options:

- Automatically based on mouse or trackpad
- When scrolling
- Always

Each act differently.

`Automatically...` with a mouse plugged in will show the scroll bars. When you are just on the trackpad, the scroll bars will be hidden until you scroll. This is the default setting.

`When scrolling` will always hide the scrollbars unless you are scrolling. If you are on a MacBook, this is probably what you are most used to seeing, so turn this on if you use a mouse occasionally and hate the look of the scroll bars. (This is how I have mine set).

`Always` will always show the scrollbars, so if you like them, they will always be there for you.

[Edit: I just saw that there was a response up at the top. Hopefully this here will help someone searching to find the answer quicker.]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.8 go to System Preferences -> General -> Show scroll bars and select "Automatically...". You probably had it set to "Always".